# javascript/jquery grids that impliment endless scrolling (as opposed to traditional paging)

Tags: datagrid, grid, infinite-scroll, endlessscroll

I recently read a [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-end-of-pagination/) about "endless pagination".  I thought it would be a good idea to try represent grid data this way.  I personally love being able to scroll down and have more data appearing rather than search for the next page.  Surprising I haven't been able to find any of the jquery/js grids that support viewing data this way.

Any suggestions of javascript/jquery grids that support endless scrolling?

Thanks

Comment: Could someone explain the down vote?  Is this a bad question? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Kendo ui has a [grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html) that supports feature with a scrollable option:

```
                    scrollable: {
                        virtual: true
                    },
```

Its not free though...

Comment: Marking this as the answer because no one else is responding.